# Overlaying a graphic on top of a video player

Tags: css, html

This may be easy if it can’t even be done. I want to overlay a top banner graphic (png) on top of this video player on my site to give the illusion of the video playing in a screen underneath a red movie-theatre style curtain on top. Here’s my code, so what kind of overlay do I need to use so the graphic will always move with my video?

```
    <div style="position: relative;">
    <div id="video-player" style="width: 600px; height: 800; margin: 0; position:relative; "> 
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 200px; left: 10px;">
    <video height="400" width="599" id="container" src="my-video-source">&nbsp;</video>
    </div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just use an [absolutely positioned element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/position). You may need to mess around with [Z-Indexes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Understanding_CSS_z-index) too

Comment: i've done a little tinkering and no matter what i do, the image always ends up sitting on top of the video and pushing the video down...any suggestions to prevent/fix that? Thanks

Comment: look at how the video is positions, try reverse margins?

Comment: I'm not familiar with reverse margins -- would that also affect how the image is overlayed too?

Comment: If you are not familiar with reverse margins, I'd say you were biting  off more than you can chew!

Comment: yes, i know! that is why I am here! :) If this really can't be done simply, then I think i will just abandon the idea -- thanks for your help.

Comment: my point is that reverse margins are simple, and therefore you might need to read a bit more about CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. Just watch your math on width's, you were breaking out of the container in your example. Also, if the curtain is 'behind' the video add z-index:9; to the .curtain class. (increment by more if needed) If your video is a youtube iframe embed then you'll need to add the opacity setting on youtube url.

```
<style>
.video_container{
    height:600px;
    padding:200px 0 0 10px;
    position:relative;
    width:590px;
}
.curtain{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
</style>


<div class="video_container">
    <video width="590" height="400" controls="controls">
        <source src="my-video-source" type="video/mp4" />
        &nbsp;
    </video>
    <img class="curtain" src="/curtain.png">
</div>
```